# I would like to place/attach text description to the right of ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three ImageViews at the bottom of cell in a ListView item. I would like to attach some Text to the right of these images so that it will stick with the ImageView.  I realize I could use Linear and relative layout for this but I thought maybe there is a way to place text next to a ImageView.

Comment: Two things will help clarify your question. First, an illustration would be nice. And second, and perhaps more importantly, show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout it work. Simple example:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParantLeft="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ImageView1" />
```

This will put textview left side = imageview left side and textview right side = imageview right side, so the content from textview will be inside your imageview. You can use all kind of positions, just read relative or linear layouts from android development properties.

But i`m not sure what is question at all :)